# PDF parser in Python

Tags: python-3.x

Autodidact and inspired by David Beazley code (to improve my skills in Python) i would like to get your feed back on this Parser code.

NB: The lazy property let the code be computed only one time if used (https://github.com/dabeaz/python-cookbook/blob/master/src/8/lazily_computed_attributes/example1.py)

```
class lazyproperty:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        else:
            value = self.func(instance)
            setattr(instance, self.func.__name__, value)
            return value


class PDFParser():
    """

    """
    def __init__(self,filepath,page_num=0):
        self.filepath = filepath
        try:
            self._doc = fitz.open(filepath)
            self.page_num = page_num
            self._page = self._doc[page_num]
        except Exception as e: 
            print("Lecture PDF impossible. {}".format(e))

    @lazyproperty
    def text(self):
        return self._page.getText()

    @lazyproperty
    def _pixs(self):
        imgs = self._doc.getPageImageList(self.page_num)
        pixs =[]
        for img in imgs:
            xref = img[0]
            pix = fitz.Pixmap(self._doc, xref)
            pixs.append(pix)
        return pixs

    @lazyproperty
    def _pixpage(self):
        pix = self._page.getPixmap(colorspace=fitz.csGRAY)
        return pix
    
    @property   
    def img(self):
        return self.imgs[0]


    @lazyproperty
    def imgs(self):
        pixs = self._pixs
        imgsarray = []
        for pix in pixs:
            img = self.pix2np(pix)
            imgsarray.append(img)
        return imgsarray
        

    def write(self,outputdir,fullpage=False):
        filename = os.path.basename(self.filepath).split('.pdf')[0]
        def writePNG(pix,filepath):
            # This is GRAY or RGB
            try:       
                pix.writePNG(filepath)
            # CMYK: convert to RGB first
            except:               
                pix = fitz.Pixmap(fitz.csRGB, pix)
                pix.writePNG(filepath)
                pix = None
        if fullpage:
            filepath = os.path.join(outputdir,'{}_p{}.png'.format(filename,self.page_num))
            pix = self._pixpage
            writePNG(pix,filepath)
            return
        pixs = self._pixs
        for i,pix in enumerate(pixs):
            filepath = os.path.join(outputdir,'{}_p{}_i{}.png'.format(filename,self.page_num,i))
            writePNG(pix,filepath)
        return

    @staticmethod
    def pix2np(pix):
        """
        Convert pixmap to image np.ndarray
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53059007/python-opencv
        param pix: pixmap
        """
        import numpy as np
        #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22236749/numpy-what-is-the-difference-between-frombuffer-and-fromstring
        im = np.frombuffer(pix.samples, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(pix.h, pix.w, pix.n)
        try:
            im = np.ascontiguousarray(im[..., [2, 1, 0]])  # rgb to bgr
        except IndexError:
            #Trick to convert Gray rto BGR, (im.reshape)
            logger.warning("Shape of image array is {}".format(im.shape)) 
            im = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
            im = np.ascontiguousarray(im[..., [2, 1, 0]])
        return im
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to code review, I have edited your title so that it states what your code does, rather than what you expect to improve. this is given in [ask]

Comment: We're missing a couple of things before we can commence with a review here. Notably, all the imports are missing. `fitz.open(filepath)` Who's fitz and where does it come from?